# exposing internet facing api using amazon web services

Tags: amazon-web-services

If I would like to expose a web-app to external internet what steps I need to follow in aws?

1. Create cloudfront or static ip or route 53? Not sure what needs to
   be exposed
2. Create WAF?
3. Create ELB?AWS ELB or nginx
4. Enforce https through webserver?
5. Any other requirements please point me through?

Comment: Too broad - all of those questions depend on your requirements. If you must start, you should begin with a we application on a single EC2 instance.

Comment: so I get a domain name and register  in  ROUTE 53 and from route 53 i route to waf elb and waf elb points to  my ec2 where webapp are running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Route53 is not a requirement at all. You can use Route53 for DNS, or you can use a third-party DNS service, or you can just use a static ip (AWS Elastic IP).

WAF is not needed just for exposing an API.

ELB is only needed if you are running this on multiple servers.

You could enforce HTTPS at the web server, or you could just leave port 80 closed and only open port 443.

At an absolute minimum you just need to deploy your application to an EC2 server, open the appropriate port(s) in the Security Group, and assign the server an Elastic IP.